# sequential execution of event listener and then form submission by pressing enter key

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have an event listener and a form. Both fires up when user presses enter key. What i want is when user presses the enter key then first event listerner should execute and then the form submission. So how to do it?

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

    // fires when enter key is pressed
     infowindow.close();
      marker.setVisible(false);
      input.className = '';
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
        input.className = 'notfound';
        return;
      }
    }

    and

    <form action="xyz.php" method="post">
    //submits when enter key is pressed
    <div id="searchWrapper" style="width:940px;margin-bottom:10px">

        <input name="txtSearch" type="text" id="txtSearch" class="search focus" placeholder="Where do you need parking?" value=<?php echo '"'.$str.'"'; ?> />

        <input class="dates search search-date" style="height:30px;background-image:url('images/sprite-master.png') ;background-position:-480px 0px; cursor:pointer;width:110px;" name="txtSearchStartDate" type="text" id="txtSearchStartDate" placeholder="today" enddate="txtSearchEndDate" />
        <input name="txtSearchEndDate" type="text" id="txtSearchEndDate" class="dates search search-date" placeholder="(optional)" />
        <input type="submit" value="  Search" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary" />
         <input name="city" id="city" type="hidden" value="">
       <input name="state" id="state" type="hidden" value="">
       <input name="country" id="country" type="hidden" value="">
          <input name="lat" id="lat" type="hidden" value="">
       <input name="long" id="long" type="hidden" value="">
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop the form onsubmit function from submitting the form, check if a place was given in `place_changed` event.  If so submit the form manually, otherwise change the input classname.

```
var form = document.getElementById("searchForm"), // I assume the form tag has the ID searchForm
    input = document.getElementById("txtSearch"),
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    // stop the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
};

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    input.className = '';
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
        // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
        input.className = 'notfound';
    } else {
        input.className = '';
        // this won't fire the onsubmit function
        form.submit();
    }
});
```